# set a variable in mysql based on case when-then

Tags: mysql, sql, case, case-when

I have a Projects table, containing three columns: **Task_ID**, **Start_Date** and **End_Date**.
I'm trying two increment a variable named **count** whenever the difference between previous row's **End_Date** and current row's **Start_Date** is not equals to zero but it's getting incremented for every row. So, how can I change the value of a variable in mysql based on CASE when-then statements?

---

SQL QUERY -

```
SET @count := 0;
SELECT
*,
LAG(end_date) OVER(ORDER BY start_date) as prev,
DATEDIFF(LAG(end_date) OVER(ORDER BY start_date), start_date) as diff,
(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(LAG(end_date) OVER(ORDER BY start_date), start_date) is NULL
    THEN @count
    WHEN DATEDIFF(LAG(end_date) OVER(ORDER BY start_date), start_date) = 0
    THEN @count
    ELSE @count := @count + 1
END) as cnt
FROM projects
;
```

OUTPUT -

```
task_id start_date end_date prev         diff cnt
1      2015-10-01 2015-10-02 NULL        NULL 1
24     2015-10-02 2015-10-03 2015-10-02   0   2
2      2015-10-03 2015-10-04 2015-10-03   0   3
23     2015-10-04 2015-10-05 2015-10-04   0   4
3      2015-10-11 2015-10-12 2015-10-05  -6   5
22     2015-10-12 2015-10-13 2015-10-12   0   6
4      2015-10-15 2015-10-16 2015-10-13  -2   7
21     2015-10-17 2015-10-18 2015-10-16  -1   8
5      2015-10-19 2015-10-20 2015-10-18  -1   9
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT -

```
task_id start_date end_date prev         diff cnt
1      2015-10-01 2015-10-02 NULL        NULL 0
24     2015-10-02 2015-10-03 2015-10-02   0   0
2      2015-10-03 2015-10-04 2015-10-03   0   0
23     2015-10-04 2015-10-05 2015-10-04   0   0
3      2015-10-11 2015-10-12 2015-10-05  -6   1
22     2015-10-12 2015-10-13 2015-10-12   0   1
4      2015-10-15 2015-10-16 2015-10-13  -2   2
21     2015-10-17 2015-10-18 2015-10-16  -1   3
5      2015-10-19 2015-10-20 2015-10-18  -1   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  Use use window functions:

```
SELECT p.*,
       SUM(diff < 0) OVER (ORDER BY start_date)
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             LAG(end_date) OVER(ORDER BY start_date) as prev,
             DATEDIFF(LAG(end_date) OVER (ORDER BY start_date), start_date) as diff
      FROM projects p
     ) p;
```

The `SUM(diff < 0)` is shorthand for `SUM(CASE WHEN diff < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.  MySQL treats booleans as integers in an arithmetic context.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works fine but can you explain this line `SUM(diff < 0) OVER (ORDER BY start_date)`. Also, just want to know whether it is doable with case statement or not.

Comment: @GauravThakur . . . Yes.  The `SUM(diff < 0)` is just a convenient shorthand that MySQL supports.

Comment: So, the same thing is not achievable by case statements?

Comment: @GauravThakur . . . I have a `CASE` expression in the revised answer.

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)